# NLog: Write to two different targets based on logger name and grouping Quartz logs

Tags: asp.net, nlog, quartz.net

I have an ASP.NET 4.7 web project where there is a Quartz.NET scheduler implemented.
I've read that Quartz.NET is using Common.Logging abstraction, but I don't know what it really means...

In order to avoid my default application log to be spammed from Quartz messages, I have configured programmatically the NLog settings, in the following way:

```
        var config = new NLog.Config.LoggingConfiguration();
        var logfile = new NLog.Targets.FileTarget("logfile")
        {
            FileName = "${basedir}/Logs/${logger}_${shortdate}.log",
            Layout = "${longdate}|${level:uppercase=true}|${aspnet-request-ip}|${aspnet-request-url}|${callsite}|${message}|${exception:format=tostring}"
        };
        var logfileQ = new NLog.Targets.FileTarget("logfile")
        {
            FileName = "${basedir}/Logs/Quartz_${shortdate}.log",
            Layout = "${longdate}|${level:uppercase=true}||${message}"
        };

        config.AddTarget(logfile);
        config.AddTarget(logfileQ);

        config.AddRule(LogLevel.Error, LogLevel.Fatal, logfileQ, "Quartz*", true);
        config.AddRule(LogLevel.Trace, LogLevel.Fatal, logfile, "*");

        // Apply config           
        NLog.LogManager.Configuration = config;
        NLog.LogManager.ReconfigExistingLoggers();
```

Then I add my application logs with the following code:

```
public class MyApiController : ApiController
{
    private static NLog.Logger logger = NLog.LogManager.GetLogger("Application");

    [HttpPost]
    [Authorize]
    public IHttpActionResult Post(DataModel.MyModel m)
    {
        logger.Warn("Unable to add point {0}: localization missing", m.Name);
    }
}
```

So NLog creates an "application_yyyy-MM-dd.log" file correctly and also a "Quartz_yyyy-MM-dd.log" file with only the error and fatal message levels.

The problem is that it creates also the following three files for Quartz containing all levels:

1. Quartz.Core.JobRunShell_2020-04-28.log
2. Quartz.Core.QuartzSchedulerThread_2020-04-28.log
3. Quartz.Simpl.SimpleJobFactory_2020-04-28.log

It seems like final=true of the first rule is ignored.

Which is the right way to configure it? Should I have to disable something in Quartz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out.

The added rules must be seen as filters, what doesn't match a filter go to the next rule.

The last one is like "take everything that has not been matching before..."

The main issue in mine rules is the first one that match only the levels Error and Fatal, but all the other levels of Quartz message step into the next rule that writes the log file.

Therefore the rules should be like this:

```
config.AddRule(LogLevel.Trace, LogLevel.Fatal, logfileQ, "Quartz*", true);
config.AddRule(LogLevel.Trace, LogLevel.Fatal, logfile, "*");
```

In this way, all the messages, of any levels, coming from Quartz will be written in the quartz_ log file.

To avoid a trace or info level of Quartz to be recorded I should add a third rule to grab also them and placed before the "grab all" rule:

```
config.AddRule(LogLevel.Warn, LogLevel.Fatal, logfileQ, "Quartz*", true);
config.AddRule(LogLevel.Trace, LogLevel.Info, noLogging, "Quartz*", true);
config.AddRule(LogLevel.Trace, LogLevel.Fatal, logfile, "*");
```

Where noLogging is a target that doesn't write anywhere or only to console